# How can I find the probability of getting a Yahtzee using probability generating functions for each roll?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I was recently taught the concept of Probability Generating Functions (PGFs) and while revising said concept, I came across a question about the game Yahtzee. The question was as follows:

> Find the probability of achieving a Yahtzee made entirely of the number $k$ on five 6-sided dice after 3 rolls. You may assume the player achieving the Yahtzee removes all of the dice which rolled $k$ after each of the 3 rolls.

Most of the answers I googled after attempting to solve this consisted of combinatorics and/or simply doing it manually or by using other ways I don't understand; however, while attempting to solve this using PGFs, I came across a curious problem in my method which I was unsure could be worked with, leading me to ask this question, this problem is explained below:

Let $X$ be the number of 6-sided dice in a game of Yahtzee that land on the number $k$ in one roll.
$X$ can be modelled binomially as $X \sim B(n,\frac{1}{6})$ for each throw where $n$ is the number of dice in each throw.
The probability generating function for $X$ is $G_X(t) = (\frac{5}{6}+\frac{1}{6}t)^n$

Thus, for the first roll, the PGF is as follows:
$G_{X_1}(t)=(\frac{5}{6}+\frac{1}{6}t)^5$
However, given the second roll is dependent on the amount of successes of the first roll, I would have to implement the first roll's outcome into the second roll's PGF:
$G_{X_2}(t)=(\frac{5}{6}+\frac{1}{6}t)^{5-X_1}$
And the third roll would implement the same concept:
$G_{X_3}(t)=(\frac{5}{6}+\frac{1}{6}t)^{5-X_1-X_2}$
This is not the answer I'm looking for since I would like $G_{X_3}(t)$ and $G_{X_2}(t)$ to be solely in terms of $t$ to then solve the question by finding the coefficient of $t^5$.

I would like to have the skill to manipulate embedded random variables in PGFs, thus my question is:
If possible, how can I implement the PGF of a random variable into the PGF of another random variable?
 (A method which I can use to solve the above question for example)

Comment: To clarify:  the player seeks five $k's$ *regardless* of what the initial roll is?  So, with $k=1$, say, if the player gets five  $6's$ they would reroll all the dice?  If so, this is very far from how the game is actually played.

Comment: Yes, I assume it was to simplify the question but I don't really know if it actually did simplify the process of finding the answer

Comment: Well..generating functions seem ill adapted to this problem.  The probability that each die comes up $k$ (given two potential rerolls) is $p=\left(1-\left(\frac 56\right)^3\right)$.  As the dice are independent, the answer is $p^5$.

Comment: My question isn't so much focused around the actual answer to the Yahtzee problem I gave, but more about the problem I ran into while attempting to solve it with PGFs: representing a random variables PGF's in terms of another random variable and attempting to solve from there. I would like to know if there's a method to solving such a situation

Comment: PGFs can be combined in different ways to represent a new random variable:
For example: For Z = X + Y, where X and Y are independent: G_Z(t)=G_X(t)*G_Y(t).
Is there a way of solving the Yahtzee problem with PGFs using a similar method/formula to the example given in this comment

Comment: I don't see how to get the "choice" embedded in the generating function, though of course it might be possible.  As I say, this does not strike me as a good way to approach the problem (which, after all, is straight forward).

Comment: yahtzee rules [here](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/yahtzee.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will say up front, that this is a really bad idea.  If ever a problem was designed to be solved Combinatorically, this is it.  How I would handle it would be to assume that the dice are labeled $D-1, D-2, \cdots D-5$.  Then, in each round, I would roll all $5$ dice.  Then, I would examine the $6^{15}$ combinations possible, to determine which of them resulted in each of $D-k$ being *hit* at least once.

I suspect that I would use Inclusion-Exclusion, and take advantage of the symmetrical aspects of the situation.

However, there is no reason that the problem can not be conquered by computing the appropriate probability function.

---

**Edit**
I should also mention that it is unclear to me whether the OP (i.e. original poster) will even regard this response as *on point*.  I have no formal knowledge of *Probability Generating Functions*, so I don't know if the analysis below is what the OP is looking for.

**Edit**
It just hit me.  I just took a very easy problem and made it very difficult.  All of the analysis from **Old Work** is valid, but unnecessary.  I left it in, because

- it might still have value
- it is an example of my not seeing the forest for the trees.

Mathematically, the problem is unchanged, if you never remove any dice.  Dice don't talk to each other.  You roll all $5$ dice all $3$ times.  The question becomes, what is the probability that all $5$ dice are each hit at least once.

This is clearly

$$\left[\frac{6^3 - 5^3}{6^3}\right]^5.$$

That is, you have $5$ independent events of each die being hit at least once.

---

**Old Work**

Taking the probability function approach, in my opinion, the best strategy is to work backwards.

At the point just before the 3rd roll, you will have $r$ dice remaining, where $r$ is some element in $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Let $f(r)$ denote the probability of achieving the Yahtzee, as a function of $r$.

Clearly, $f(0) = 1$, which represents that you have achieved the Yahtzee before the 3rd roll.

For $r \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$, you have that $f(r) = 6^{-r}.$ 
This formula also works for $r = 0$.

---

Now, consider the situation at the point just before the 2nd roll.

At the point just before the 2nd roll, you will have $r$ dice remaining, where $r$ is some element in $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Let $g(r)$ denote the probability of achieving the Yahtzee, as a function of $r$.

Clearly, $g(0) = 1$, which represents that you have achieved the Yahtzee before the 2nd roll.

For $r \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$, you have that there are $(r+1)$ different outcomes possible.  That is, for a specific value of $r$, the 2nd roll will result in their being $s$ dice left, where $s$ is some element in $\{0,1,2,\cdots,r\}$

What is necessary here is to compute, for a specific value of $r$, the probability of each event $s$ occurring.  Then, with each event $s$ occurring, your probability of success on the 3rd roll will be $f(s) = 6^{-s}.$

---

I find it helpful here to stretch intuition, by looking at a specific example.

Suppose that just before the 2nd roll, you have $3$ dice remaining.

First, see [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution),
specifically $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k} p^k q^{n-k}.$

If there are $3$ dice remaining just before the 2nd roll, then the probability of having $s$ dice remaining after the 2nd roll ($s \in \{0,1,2,3\}$) is

$$\binom{3}{s}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^s \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{3-s}
= \binom{3}{s}\frac{5^s}{6^3}.$$

For each such value of $s$, you then multiply the probability of the above event occurring by $f(s)$.

Therefore,

$$g(3) = \sum_{s=0}^3 \binom{3}{s}\frac{5^s}{6^3} \times \frac{1}{6^s}
= \sum_{s=0}^3 \binom{3}{s}\frac{5^s}{6^{3+s}}.$$

Consequently, it becomes easy to generalize:

$$g(r) = \sum_{s=0}^r \binom{r}{s}\frac{5^s}{6^{r+s}}. \tag1 $$
Note that this formula (also) works, for $r = 0.$

---

Now, imagine that you are at the point just before the 1st roll.

At the end of the 1st roll, there will be $r$ dice left, where $r$ is some element in $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}.$

Let $h(r)$ denote the probability of having $r$ dice remaining, after the first roll.

Then, the probability of a Yahtzee is

$$\sum_{r=0}^5 \left[h(r) \times g(r)\right].$$

$g(r)$ is given by (1) above.  A similar use of the binomial theorem will allow $h(r)$ to be computed.

$$h(r) = \binom{5}{r}\left(\frac{5^r}{6^5}\right).$$

Putting this all together, starting from scratch, the probability of the Yahtzee is

$$\sum_{r=0}^5 \left\{ ~\binom{5}{r}\left(\frac{5^r}{6^5}\right) \times 
\left[\sum_{s=0}^r \binom{r}{s}\frac{5^s}{6^{r+s}}\right]
 ~\right\}
.$$